# Como passar a variável em PostgreSQL usando dbblink

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql, query, variáveis

Estou com a seguinte `query` no `PostgreSQL`:

```
declare $1 VARCHAR;
    BEGIN
         IF 
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tempo2
            WHERE looping IS NULL) > 0
            THEN
           $1 = (SELECT banco FROM tempo2 WHERE looping IS NULL LIMIT 1);
INSERT INTO...
       SELECT * FROM dblink ('host=xx.xx.xx.xx dbname='||$1||' 
                                 user=xxxxpassword=xxxxx',
        'SELECT ...
```

Meu problema é que o banco não está lendo a variavel '||`$1`||', acredito que quando ela é lida no `SELECT` o conteúdo dela já venha com ' (aspas simples), exemplo: `SELECT * FROM dblink ('host=xx.xx.xx.xx dbname=''variavel''...`

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Qual a mensagem de erro? Está usando função sql ou plpgsql? Consegue enviar o código completo ou elaborar um exemplo no sqlfiddle.com?

Comment: Ele não da mensagem de erro, o insert nao é realizado na tabela destino.
Exemplo:
DO $$ declare $1 VARCHAR;
BEGIN
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tempo2 WHERE looping IS NULL)> 0
         THEN
$1 = (SELECT banco FROM tempo2 WHERE looping IS NULL LIMIT 1); INSERT INTO tabelaCriada(a ,b ,c ,d ,e ,f) SELECT * FROM dblink ('host=xx.xx.xx.xx port=x dbname='||$1|' user=x password=x', 'SELECT (SELECT a, b, c, d, e, f -- O corpo do select ta ok ) as x (a VARCHAR ,b VARCHAR ,c TIMESTAMP ,d VARCHAR, e VARCHAR ,f VARCHAR);
 UPDATE tempo2 set looping = 'T' WHERE banco = $1; END IF;END; $$;

Comment: Se o problema for as aspas talvez o `quote_literal` resolva